# Multiple domains on single host plan on GoDaddy problem with redirection

Tags: hosting, redirect, godaddy, domain

I have a goDaddy account for hosting and on that host i have multiple domains. goDaddy offers me only one 404 redirect for all of my domains:

```
* example2.com/gadf (nonexistent link) is redirected to example1.com
* example3.com/sagsdg (nonexistent link) is redirected to example1.com
```

I need for one of my domains to make the redirect on the same domain:

```
* example4.com/gsdhgfhf (nonexistent link) to be redirected to example4.com
```

Can someone please help me?

I am on Windows and I'm using Wordpress on all of my domains. I tried to look for web.config but didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, you can specify your 404 page in your .htaccess file.  If you are on Windows / ASP.Net, you can specify your 404 page in a web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the domains to simply redirect to the root of that site, you should be able to specify the redirection link as "/".