# 404 Error Behavior on Godaddy

Tags: hosting, godaddy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple domains on single host plan on GoDaddy problem with redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/69372/multiple-domains-on-single-host-plan-on-godaddy-problem-with-redirection)

My goDaddy account for hosting and on that host i have multiple domains. goDaddy offers me only one 404 redirect for all of my domains:

- domain1.com/gadfgsdf (nonexistent link) is redirected to domain1.com
- domain2.com/gadf (nonexistent link) is redirected to domain1.com
- domain.com/sagsdg (nonexistent link) is redirected to domain1.com

I need for one of my domains to make the redirect on the same domain:

- domain4.com/gsdhgfhf (nonexistent link) to be redirected to domain4.com

I am on Windows and i am using Wordpress on all of my domains. I looked for the web.config file but didn't find it. I new at this and i would really appreciate it if you can explain more detailed.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not create multiple copies of the same question, if you have information to add, add it to your origional question:
http://serverfault.com/questions/69372/multiple-domains-on-single-host-plan-on-godaddy-problem-with-redirection

Answer (score 0):

If it's hosted on an Apache box you could use the .htaccess file to make the error redirects - full urls and even html are possible http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess2.shtml

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/badrequest.html
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/authreqd.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbid.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/serverr.html 

ErrorDocument 401 "<body bgcolor=#ffffff><h1>You have
 to actually <b>BE</b> a <a href="#">member</A> to view 
this page, Colonel!
```